# Remove package installed with make

Tags: uninstall, make, github

I was testing out ways to get better gestures on my laptop, someone on reddit suggested [this](https://github.com/p2rkw/xf86-input-mtrack), I installed it following [this](https://int3ractive.com/2018/09/make-the-best-of-MacBook-touchpad-on-Ubuntu.html) guide.

It worked, but I don't really like it, so I want to now remove it. Except I have no idea how. I tried finding it in my installed packages with

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep -i mtrack
```

But that didn't find anything. What should I do?

Edit: Going to the install folder and running `sudo make uninstall` results in this:

```
 /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=uninstall rm -f '/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/mtrack_drv.la'
```

Comment: Go to the installation folder and run `sudo make uninstall`

Comment: Done and update the op, I don't think it actually uninstalled it

Comment: why do you think so?

Comment: It didn't give me any kind of indication that it was uninstalled

Comment: Please test it and see if it's still there!

Comment: Success with make and other commands often has no feedback. Use exit codes to check for success or failure, or simply look and see if the installed files are gone. Apt only works on deb packages, not make, not snaps, not pip, not anything else, so that result is expected.

Comment: Nevermind I'm an idiot I forgot to log out. It worked!

Comment: Read `man bash`, the `PROMPTING` section and you can put the shell variable "`$?`" (status of last command) in your prompt. In mine it's in '()'. `walt@bat:~(0)$ rm no`
`rm: cannot remove 'no': No such file or directory`
`walt@bat:~(1)$`

Answer (score 2):

In general, running `make uninstall` will work, but the `uninstall` target is not guraranteed to exist an ALL `makefile`s.

By using the `installwatch` program (part of the `checkinstall` package), and *re*installing the software (`sudo installwatch [options] make install`, you can find out which files are altered, and manually delete them.

**DESCRIPTION**

```
   installwatch is a program that is used in order to track the changes made while installing
   local software (i.e.  "make install"). It monitors the requested command, and  produces  a
   log  which  indicates  all  created and modified files. By default it outputs to syslog(3)
   using a priority of "LOG_USER | LOG_INFO". This may be overridden by the  use  of  the  -o
   flag. The log format is as follows:

   <return-value> <syscall-name> <argument> #<comment>

   Each  field  is  delimited  by  a "^I" character if logging to syslog(3), or by a tab when
   logging to a file.
```